# If $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(e^{\frac{k}{n}\ln\sin x}-e^{\frac{k}{n+1}\ln\sin x})$ where $0<x<\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> If $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(e^{\frac{k}{n}\ln\sin x}-e^{\frac{k}{n+1}\ln\sin x})$ where $0<x<\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)dx=-\frac{\pi}{k}\ln4$, then the value of $k$ is?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(e^{\frac{k}{n}\ln\sin x}-e^{\frac{k}{n+1}\ln\sin x})=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(\sin^{\frac{k}{n}}x-\sin^{\frac{k}{n+1}}x)$$
That's how far I was able to solve the limit.

$$0<\sin x<1$$

For $\sin^{\frac{1}{n}}x$, when $n$ becomes very large, the value tends to $1$.

When $n\to\infty$, $n+1$ and $n$ become same and hence the value of $\sin^{\frac{k}{n}}x-\sin^{\frac{k}{n+1}}x)$
tendsds to zero. Am I correct?

Comment: Is the limit really $x\to\infty$? That does look like a clear typo (is it $n\to\infty$)?

Comment: I am so sorry. It's n tending to infinity

Comment: No worries. By the way, the value of the integral looks strange (it is valid, but I would have expected a $2$ instead of the $k$ in the denominator, for the sake of an exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Taylor expansions here. Note that for any fixed $x\in(0,\pi)$, $k$ and $\ln \sin x$ are constants (and $\sin x > 0$ so we are good with regard to taking the logarithm, by the way), so that $\frac{k\ln \sin x}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. 
We then have, setting $u=k\ln\sin x$ for convenience
$$
\begin{align}
e^{\frac{u}{n}}-e^{\frac{u}{n+1}} 
&= 1+ \frac{u}{n} + \frac{u^2}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) - \left(1+ \frac{u}{n+1} + \frac{u^2}{2(n+1)^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) \\
&=  \frac{u}{n} + \frac{u^2}{n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) - 
\left(\frac{u}{n} - \frac{u}{n^2} + \frac{u^2}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) \\
&= \frac{u}{n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
so that
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\left( \frac{k\ln\sin x}{n^2}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( k\ln\sin x + o\left(1\right) \right) = k\ln\sin x.
$$
We then have 
$$
-2\frac{\pi}{k}\ln 2 = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f = k\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} dx \ln\sin x = -k\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2
$$
and you can find $k$. (I used Mathematica to compute the integral.)

Comment: It was a typo. Your right. It's $n\to\infty$

Comment: What could have been interesting is the computation of $\int \log(sin(x))\, dx$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Agreed. Not sure if that's the main part of the OP's question, but it definitely looks non-trivial.